# jQuery AJAX(GET)-Called PHP module ignores single letter a as a passed parameter

Tags: php, ajax

Am using jQuery 3.1.1.  In a $.get call, if I pass the single letter a (upper or lowercase with encodeURI) the called PHP module ignores it.  Any other letter is accepted and processed. If I pass 2 letters they are processed correctly even if the passed string starts with the letter a. I can see via Firebug that the letter a is being passed to the called PHP module OK but there is no response or error indication.  Any ideas or suggestions will be most appreciated.  Here's the first few lines of the called PHP module:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<response>";

$error = FALSE;

// the first few letters being passed to this module
if (!empty($_GET['params'])) 
    {
        $first_few = urldecode($_GET['params']);
    } 
else 
    {
        $error = TRUE;
        echo '<error>parameters</error>';
    }
```

Additional info:

The calling code is:

```
var params = "params=";
params += String ($('#dogname_start').val());
params = encodeURI(params);
$('#add_appointment').submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
$.get(
    './modules/get_dognames.xml.php',
    params,
    handle_response,
    "xml"   
    );  // end get
```

I have  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); set

More information and thanks for the interest and queries:

The environment that this is running in is:
. Windows 7 - 64 bit
. Localhost via XAMPP (Apache, PHP and MySQL)
. Firefox (50.1.0) and IE11 - the issue is the same in both.

Am using plain PHP (5.5.3).

Finally found the issue - it was an ampersand coded as the ASCII code for it in the XML response data - it was nothing to do with the letter a per se - it just happened that the database lookup using the letter a returned some data with the ampersand in it and I changed the ampersand to the ASCII character for it before sending the XML data stream back to the calling module.

Thanks to those who tried to help.

Comment: can you provide more info on this?

Comment: I am sure it is not frontend issue. The problem is in server side.

Comment: You are using Plain PHP or some kind of framework?

Comment: It should be noted that jQuery's examples for [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) do not have any code like what you're showing here. By running `encodeURI` you are encoding that `=`, which is likely not what you want to do. Also, `val` returns a string, so passing it to the `String` constructor is overkill.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, of course I changed your php code to show the value of the **params** parameter. So my guess is there is maybe a problem in your php code after the line: `$first_few = urldecode($_GET['params']);` To be sure, try to just put: `echo $first_few; die();`

Comment: Hi B. Assem - thank you for your suggestions. I removed the "String" overkill as well as the encodeURI. Now works fine in Firefox but still nothing in Internet Explorer 11.  There is no response whatsoever from the called PHP module when I pass it just the single letter a, though, as mentioned, I can see it being passed.